# Xamarin debugging disabled in android project properties

Tags: debugging, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I run my app on my physical device however debugging is disabled and I can not trace the logs.

The error message that shows up is "Debugging disabled in android project properties".

I search the properties but i cant find anything.

Comment: i am having the same problem. did you find a solution?

Comment: yes, it was a dumb thing, i forget to check the debug in the run tab

Answer (score 0):

Very simple,

1. Goto Build
2. Configuration Manager
3. Check the Android project checkbox under deploy section

Goodluck!

Comment: did you restart vs?

Comment: its very blurr but i understand, can you tell us your property config what is your target platform and all

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Karlomanio can you elaborate your issue

Comment: Just as described.  I'm getting the "Debugging disabled in android project properties" error and I followed these steps and it didn't work.  It started happening after I set up a network_security_config.xml file.  I removed the reference to it in the AndroidManifest and deleted the Obj and bin files.  I still had the error.